# Showing an Icon in the Overflow Menu

Tags: java, android, contextmenu, android-toolbar

I am trying to display action overflow menu with icons in my one application. I am not getting icons in menu. My **Target SDK = 23** and **Minimum SDK = 16.**

[image]

My **Menu.xml** is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<!-- Single menu item
     Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
-->
<item android:id="@+id/menu_donate"
      android:icon="@drawable/new_facebook_page"
      android:title="@string/facebook"
      app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/new_facebook_page" 
      android:title="@string/facebook"
      app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
      android:icon="@drawable/new_facebook_page"
      android:title="@string/facebook" 
      app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

and **Java code** is like below

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
```

But it does not showing icons in menu. Let me know if anyone can help me to achieve this without changing menu structure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below line to your java class inside `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`:

```
 menu.add(0, 1, 1, menuIconWithText(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.user_2), getResources().getString(R.string.action_profile)));
```

[image]

Try with below code :

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
//        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_patient_home_screen, menu);


        menu.add(0, 1, 1, menuIconWithText(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.user_2), getResources().getString(R.string.action_profile)));
        menu.add(0, 2, 2, menuIconWithText(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.add_user), getResources().getString(R.string.action_add_user)));
        menu.add(0, 3, 3, menuIconWithText(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.switch_profile), getResources().getString(R.string.action_switch_profile)));
        menu.add(0, 4, 4, menuIconWithText(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.logout), getResources().getString(R.string.action_sign_out)));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(PatientHomeScreen.this, "Profile is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(PatientHomeScreen.this, "Add New User is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case 3:
                Toast.makeText(PatientHomeScreen.this, "Switch Profile is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case 4:
                Toast.makeText(PatientHomeScreen.this, "Sign Out is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private CharSequence menuIconWithText(Drawable r, String title) {

        r.setBounds(0, 0, r.getIntrinsicWidth(), r.getIntrinsicHeight());
        SpannableString sb = new SpannableString("    " + title);
        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(r, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        return sb;
    }
```

Or, you can show icon with menu item by :

xml code :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_alarm"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_accept"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/menu_create_alarm"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
```

Java Code :

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.menu_item, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: if I use XML solution, its showing menu in toolbar. I do not want show it on toolbar. Thanks

Comment: Welcome , Happy to help you @Priyanka

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom layout for menu item child

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<!-- Single menu item
     Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
-->
<item android:id="@+id/menu_donate"
      android:title="@string/facebook"
      android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_donate_layout"
      app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
      android:title="@string/facebook"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_setting_layout"
      app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
      android:title="@string/facebook" 
    android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_logut_layout"
      app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Create `menu_donate_layout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Profile" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Same create the separate layout of each menu item or change text and icon dynamically.